# Is this a geode?

Tags: geology

So just having issues with identification looks like a outer line of rock  a bit transparent but the inside polished looks waxy other side of stone a bit more foggy but still blue visible[image][image]

***Edit - extra info from OP supplied in a comment, added here***

Rough on the edge like stone and scratched just now with dime no real damage just a mark of the dime being dragged on the surface. Found this when I moved in to house previous owner left it he was Vietnamese. Inside looks like minerals form edge moving up toward center

Comment: Yes, this is a geode.